# Tomcat change URL www.mydomain.com/webapp by www.mydomain.com

Tags: tomcat

i have the domain www.desiem.com available.
    The problem is when charge my MENU.WAR in tomcat of my hosting, I proceed to call my page, writing www.desiem.com and shows nothing.
But when called with: www.desiem.com/MENU/ , if showed the page properly.

```
My web page is developed in Netbeans 7.1
Version of Tomcat is 1.6.0_35-b10

I hope it is just a change in the web.xml

Attach web.xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <!--<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>-->
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index13.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

Please, your support.
Thanks
John
```

Comment: You do realize there are two web.xml files..  One, under /tomcat/conf/web.xml which is the default.  There is another under your /tomcat/webapps/MENU/WEB-INF/web.xml ..  You may want to be sure you update the war file once you get this sorted for any subsequent re-deployments

Comment: Hi , thanks for you time..
The tomcat I'm using is of my provider of Hosting "DailyRazor"
I have that tell them to make a change in your web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to rename your war file to `ROOT.war`.